# Idling CPU at 65C, re-place or re-paste?

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer

Replaced Graphics card because screen would go black at a certain temp while gaming, but sound would stay on (but locked up). Then with replacement card whole PC shuts off during gaming now because the CPU is overheating.

Note: CPU is only supposed to go up to 71C max according to manufacturer and it goes well over upon load.

System Temp: 30C

TL;DR: Idling CPU at 65C, started to shut down due to overheating, re-place (CPU, or CPU and Motherboard) or re-paste?

Comment: What's the ambient temperature?

Comment: Ambient system is 30C

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the room.

Comment: tbh no clue, I assume though if the motherboard is idling at around 30C most the time that the room must be around that or lower, also, new graphics card idles at 28C

Comment: If the computer is shutting down because its overheating then you should reapply the paste before you replace the cpu.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible there is not enough paste, although most likely there is too much. Also, make sure the fan is working normally.

Comment: clean the processor surface with alcohol (the closest the solution is to 100% alcohol the best) in order to remove the old paste. then, apply new paste, only enough to cover the contact surface with the sink with a density not too thin but also not too thick. (a lot of paste is **not** better than less paste.) finally, clean your fan/heatsink and if the architecture allows it, place the heatsink/fan screwing or fixating it in diagonal, to ensure full contact and heat transmission.